# Python Functions and Operators

Tags: python, operators, radix

I am a beginner learning Python programming languages and I need you to explain in simple terms how an operator works with the given example.

I stumbled upon this thing called assignment operators:

```
x=1

y=3

x!=y
```

From the given example, the example is:

`x=1` and means `x=1`

`x+=1` and means `x=x+1`

`x-=2` and means `x=x-2`

`x*=5` and means `x=x*5`

1. When should assignment operators be used? In what kinds of situation, (with an example/scenario will you use these operators to solve?
2. How do you apply a hexidecimal in a given situation or octal string? The following three functions I have trouble understanding how they work. If possible, explain it in simple terms. Thank you!

`hex(x)` or `oct(x)`

`chr(u)`

`ord(x)`

Comment: Stack overflow isn't here to do your homework. If there is part of the question that you don't understand then ask a clarifying question and we can try to help you correct or clarify your understanding.

Comment: `x=1` means "create a variable named x, and assign it the value 1".

Answer (score -1):

Assignment operators are just shorthand, and you would usually use them in some sort of reduction operator, e.g.

```
dot_prod = 0
for a,b in zip(vector1,vector2):
  dot_prod += a * b
```

chr() and ord() are mirror operations to convert characters to their ASCII index and back, e.g. ord('A') is 65, etc. For any given character, `chr(ord(x)) == x`

Comment: I think the OP is describing even plain `=` as an "assignment operator", and that's not shorthand for anything. Beyond that, in Python, the in-place operators are not merely short-hand; for immutable types, sure, they act mostly as a short-hand, but for mutable types, `x += y` is an inplace operation (more efficient, and aliases will see the change too), while `x = x + y` is producing a brand new value and rebinding to it. `+=` is also typically less type-strict (`mylist += (1, 2)` works, `mylist = mylist + (1, 2)` does not).